# How to draw a rectangle on a wx.StaticBitmap image in wxpython

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

How can I draw a rectangle on an my wx.StaticBitmap image called "bitmap_1" using a dc.Rectangle? I have co-ordinates((754, 483)) on where the rectangle must be drawn.

dc.DrawRectangle(10, 10, 200, 200)` this gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Foster\Documents\Roland\ims project\newtagging2.py", line 129, in OnImageMouseOver
NameError: global name 'dc' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you haven't defined what dc is.

You want to take a look at [`wxMemoryDC`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MemoryDC-class.html).

MemoryDC creates a DC that can be used to draw to bitmaps in memory (as opposed to the display)

You'll want to draw on `bitmap_1` before passing it to `StaticBitmap` like this:

```
dc= wx.MemoryDC(bitmap_1)
dc.DrawRectangle(10,10,200,200)
dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap) #This de-selects the bitmap
```

[This article](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/gdi/) should help you using DCs as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I want to draw onto the StaticBitmap called "bitmap_1", it is an image. Basically I'm creating  photo viewer and need to show where the tags are on an image and I would like to do this by displaying a rectangle where the object/person in image was tagged.

Comment: You can still do this with the above method, you can draw onto the bitmap, then call `SetBitmap` on the `StaticBitmap` to update the display.